# Clarification with Underscore Function

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am practicing JavaScript by rewriting some Underscore functions. I got a little confused by the collections example on [underscorejs.org](http://underscorejs.org/#collections) which has the following:

> **map** `_.map(list, iteratee, [context])` *Alias: **collect***
>
> Produces a new array of values by mapping each value in **list** through a transformation function (**iteratee**). If **list** is a JavaScript object, **iteratee**'s arguments will be `(value, key, list)`.
>
> ```
> _.map([1, 2, 3], function(num){ return num * 3; });
> => [3, 6, 9]
> _.map({one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}, function(num, key) { return num * 3; });
> => [3, 6, 9]
> ```

I rewrote this function like this:

```
var map = function(list, func){
    var newArr = [];
    for(prop in list){
        newArr.push(func(list[prop]));   
    }    
    return newArr;    
};
```

I am confused by the second example where they use an object as input. I would write their example as

```
map({ one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }, function(num) { return num * 3; })
```

but why do they have two arguments in their callback function:

```
function(num, key){ return num * 3; }
```

and I only have one. Am I missing something in this underscore function? Did I rewrite it properly?

Comment: Well, an Object is a *key-value* pair; vs an Array which only has an item value. That is why there are two arguments.

Comment: The second argument will be the array index, when list is an array and will be the key from the object element when the list is as object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at the source code, shall we?

### UnderscoreJS: [`_.map()`](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-17)

```
_.map = _.collect = function (obj, iteratee, context) {
  if (obj == null)
    return [];
        
  iteratee = _.iteratee(iteratee, context);
    
  var keys = obj.length !== +obj.length && _.keys(obj), // Get the Object keys
      length = (keys || obj).length,                    // Get the keys' length
      results = Array(length),                          // Array to store results
      currentKey;                                       // Keep ref to current key
    
  for (var index = 0; index < length; index++) {        // Loop from 0 -> key.length
    currentKey = keys ? keys[index] : index;            // Objects use keys[index]
    results[index] = iteratee(
      obj[currentKey],                                  // Value of object key
      currentKey,                                       // The current key
      obj);                                             // Object argument
  } 
    
  return results;                                       // Return the arr of results
};
```

Comment: whoa, I guess I have a long way to go.

Comment: Their annotated source code should help you out a lot.